# How to display bokeh DataTable with vertical scroll bar at the top

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Currently when I render datatable on bokeh, it always has the scroll bar at the bottom to show the last bit of data. How can I change it to display top data with scroll bar at the top.

Thanks!

Comment: @bigreddot Help! I have the same problem!